# GA4 Conversions only showing up in Google Tag Manager Preview Mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When I visit my website in the GTM Preview mode and complete the conversions, they will show up on the GA4 Debug tool and after 24 hours, they will also appear in the reports but none of the visits or conversions I do outside of the Preview mode come through in my GA4 reports or in the debug tool.

Comment: This is likely because you didn't publish the container and you're just previewing a workspace that has unpublished conversion implementation in it? Check the overview of the workspace you're previewing. Make sure it's empty.

Comment: Thank you. I'm seeing most of my conversions come through now.  I'll keep trouble shooting the others. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the GTM container has not been published.

When you're working on changes in your GTM container, the changes are in "Limbo" and can only be tested through the preview option. Once your previews show that everything works as intended, you're supposed to publish the changes to appropriate environment (in vast majority of cases, to the live environment).

Only after publishing your changes to the live environment will you see them reflected in production.